# Crear variable categórica en python desde un string PYTHON

Tags: string, pandas, jupyter

necesito categorizar mis observaciones por macrozonas (Norte, Centro, Centro Sur, Sur y Austral), y la variable de región está escrita por el nombre de la región.

Pensé asignarle un número a cada región y luego categorizarlas, pero creo que debe haber un método más eficiente de hacerlo.

Es mi primer post y estoy recién empezando a programar para aplicarlo a mi tesis del magíster en economía, por lo que les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Edit, aquí el código que intenté realizar

`df_merged['region'] = df_merged['region'].astype('category')`

Comment: Me encantaría ayudarte, pero es necesario que enseñes lo que has intentado hasta el momento. No sé de que macrozonas hablas.

Comment: Estimado, acabo de editar mi publicacion con el código con el que he intentado categorizar la variable.

La cosa es la siguiente: Mi variable de region está en string, y quiero categorizarla por macrozonas geográficas (espero sea el concepto correcto) Norte grande = regiones de arica y parinacota, antofagasta, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Si utilizas Pandas, lo más fácil es usar

```
pd.get_dummies(df_merged['region'])
```

Si usas Scikit, puedes usar [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), u otro encoder.

Comment: Buenísimo! Si, estoy utilizando Pandas, muchas gracias

Comment: @SergioMuñozMartinez si la respuesta te sirvió recuerda marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya has convertido la columna a tipo categórico como lo muestras.

```
df_merged['region'] = df_merged['region'].astype('category')
```

Puedes simplemente obtener los códigos internos que usa pandas cuando la clase es categoría.

```
df_merged['region_codes'] = df_merged['region'].cat.codes
```